# Are questions about what a product is worth on-topic here?

Tags: support, allowed-topics, specific-question

My friends wants to buy a computer from me but we don't know what is it worth. Is money the right place to ask what a Dell Latitude E7450 is worth selling for or is there some other place where I can ask?

Comment: The best place would be to search online at eBay or other such market places and find out the approx cost. You can then decide what is the fair price.

Answer (score 8):

It's definitely off-topic for money - as per the [off-topic list](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> - Requests for specific investment buy/sell advice; e.g. "should I sell
>     X?" or "should I buy Y?" or "will X continue to go up?"
> - Questions about shopping; e.g. "where can I buy the cheapest X?"

I doubt it would be on-topic for any other SE site, as this kind of question is very specialised and unlikely to be of any general interest.